# Adding event handler in main() for SerialPort

Tags: c#, event-handling, idisposable

I try to subscribe a event handler to the data received event. Seems like I cant specify the event handler function name. I dont understand why

```
myComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(comPort_DataReceived);
```

is giving me error message.

Here is the problem, hope anyone can answer it.

```
namespace serialport
{
    public class Program
    {

        internal List<Byte> portBuffer = new List<Byte>(1024);

        static void Main()
        {


            //1. find available COM port
            string[] nameArray = null;
            string myComPortName = null;
            nameArray = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            if (nameArray.GetUpperBound(0) >= 0)
            {
                myComPortName = nameArray[0];
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                return;
            }


            //2. create a serialport object
            // the port object is closed automatically by use using()
            SerialPort myComPort = new SerialPort();
            myComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(comPort_DataReceived);
            myComPort.PortName = myComPortName;
            //the default paramit are 9600,no parity,one stop bit, and no flow control



            //3.open the port
            try
            {
                myComPort.Open();
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            //Add timeout, p161

            //reading Bytes
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[10];
            Int32 count;
            Int32 numberOfReceivedBytes;
            myComPort.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 9);
            for (count = 0; count <= 3; count++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(byteBuffer[count].ToString());
            }


        }
        //The event handler should be static??
        void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int numberOfBytesToRead;
            numberOfBytesToRead = myComPort.BytesToRead;
            byte[] newReceivedData = new byte[numberOfBytesToRead];
            myComPort.Read(newReceivedData, 0, numberOfBytesToRead);
            portBuffer.AddRange(newReceivedData);
            ProcessData();
        }
        private void ProcessData()
        {
            //when 8 bytes have arrived, display then and remove them from the buffer
            int count;
            int numberOfBytesToRead = 8;

            if (portBuffer.Count >= numberOfBytesToRead)
            {
                for (count = 0; count < numberOfBytesToRead; count++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine((char)(portBuffer[count]));
                }
                portBuffer.RemoveRange(0, numberOfBytesToRead);
            }
        }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your event handler, myComPort isn't in scope - it's declared locally in your main() method. I would suggest that you extract the com port handling into a class and make myComPort a member variable of that class.

Also, your comments note that the SerialPort class has a managed resource that it needs to dispose of using the IDisposable / Using pattern, but you don't have a using block wrapping the access to the comm port.

Last, the method you are adding as the event handler exists as an instance member rather than as a static member; to access it from the main() method's static scope, you need to either grab it from an instance of the class or make the method static.

Answer (score 6):

First, since method `Main` is static, you can only call other static methods in the same class. As it is, `comPort_DataReceived` is declared as an instance method, the following code should fix the assignment of the event handler:

```
static void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   // ...
}
```

Second, since `myComPort` is defined in `Main`, it will not be visible in `comPort_DataReceived`. You have two choices: either declare `myComPort` as a static member of your class, or use the `sender` argument of the event handler:

```
static void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for casting the sender. Some refactoring might be better but the principle of casting the sender is massively useful to know for any event usage.

Comment: pretty important refactoring is definitively necessary if you want a proper C# program that follows OOP principles. I also omitted the fact that other instance methods and variables will still be a problem, I tried to keep the answer pedagogical instead of just providing the code I'd have used myself, so a little further research is necessary ;)

Comment: So declare a method static makes it belong to a type rather to a instance, right? if so, should we always declare the event handler as static? I guess if i put mycomport as a member of the class, then it should visible to all the methods, right?

Comment: Your first phrase is correct. As for the rest, you will quickly write programs with more than one class. You will probably be creating instances of these classes, so you'll be needing more instance methods, properties and fields. Your example in this question is special because everything happens in the program's start up class and method, which happens to be static, but this rarely happens.

Comment: Hi madd0, after i made the mycomport a member of the class, the old problem is solved, however, mycomport become invisible to the Main, what happened here?

Comment: well, I'm betting it's not static... come to the c# channel in chat if you want more help

Answer (score 0):

[Tetsujin no Oni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93922/tetsujin-no-oni)'s answer is the ideal way to handle your issue with scope. Another approach that also works is to declare `myComPort` as a static member of your Program, e.g.:

```
internal List<Byte> portBuffer = new List<Byte>(1024);
private SerialPort myComPort = new SerialPort();
```

Then simply remove the `myComPort` declaration from your `main` method.

Comment: But oh the threading issues you could create getting into THAT habit.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni Of course - I wasn't suggesting that OP make it a habit :) I've written enough socket-based apps to know how painful it is to have deadlocks on a single thread.

Comment: I wanted to be sure there was awareness of the issue, since the OP had mentioned being new to C#.